# Spring Controller Unit test, returning Null pointer exception

Tags: spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockmvc

**Im getting the following Error on running unit test for Spring controller: JavaNull pointer error In line :mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("http://localhost:8080/1"))**
My intention is to write unit test case for imagecontroller. Suggest any other alternative also. The image controller is taking image from Mysql database and rendering it in localhost server.

**This is my ImageController class**

```
        @RestController
        @RequestMapping
        public class ImageController {
        @Autowired
        private ImageRepository imageRepository;
            // Return the image from the database using ResponseEntity
            @GetMapping("/{id}")
            public ResponseEntity<byte[]> fromDatabaseAsResEntity(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) throws 
            SQLException {
                Optional<DicomImage> dicomimage = imageRepository.findById(id);
                byte[] imageBytes = null;
                if (dicomimage.isPresent()) {
                    imageBytes = dicomimage.get().getPhoto().getBytes(1,
                            (int) dicomimage.get().getPhoto().length());
                    System.out.print(imageBytes.length);
                }
                return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG).body(imageBytes);
            }       
    }
```

**This is the ImageControllerTest class**

```
        @SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
        class ImageControllerTest2 {
        @LocalServerPort
        private int port;
        @Autowired
        private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;
        private MockMvc mockMvc;
        @InjectMocks
        private ImageController imagecontroller;
        @Before
        public void setUp() throws Exception {
            mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(imagecontroller).build();
        }
        @Test
        void test() throws Exception {
            mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("http://localhost:8080/1"))
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.content().contentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG));
            }
    }
```

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.ge.controller.ImageControllerTest2.test(ImageControllerTest2.java:41)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)

Comment: What is the line number 41 in ImageControllerTest2 ?

Comment: This: mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("http://localhost:8080/1"))

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting the error, because you `mockMvc` variable is null, it does not get initialized, because your `setUp()` method is not called by the framework.

*Replace the `setup()` method's `@Before` (JUnit 4) annotation with `@BeforeEach` (JUnit 5, org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach).*

I've reproduced your example and the test passed with `@BeforeEach`.
(tested with: Springboot 2.4.4, dependencies: spring-boot-starter-web, spring-boot-starter-test)

Comment: Changed Before to BeforeEach. Now it gives me this error: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Now it is very likely that the test request successfully reached your controller method, and the NullPointerException occurs during the execution of your business logic inside the controller. Examine the stacktrace to identify the exact line where the exception is thrown.
Try to comment out the logic in your method, keep only the return statement with some dummy value, for example: return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG).body(new byte[500]);
If the test passes this way, then the exception comes from the previously commented code. Maybe because incomplete test data.

Comment: Make sure that the result of dicomimage.get().getPhoto() is not null. It can be the cause of the NullPointerException. You can also try to call http://localhost:8080/1 from postman or a browser, so not from test code. If an exception occurs that way, the same result can be expected when running the test.

Comment: Ya I commented dicomimage.get().getPhoto() and passed dummy value. It worked. Exception is due to dicomimage.get().getPhoto(). But when I run the springboot app in localhost it renders the Jpg image and Postman also returns the Jpg image. That means the logic is correct. Then why it throws error while unit testing with mockmvc?

Comment: This worked: this.mockMvc.perform(get("/1")).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk())
  .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG));